# Parsing XML data with php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to pull text from a single element in an xml file, i was able to pull the entire file but i really only need a couple of lines from the file...

On this page i was able to pull the entire xml file ( http://smyrnainlet.com/testing.php )

But when i try to just single out one line from that file.
http://smyrnainlet.com/current_data.php

This is the error i am receiving:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getbyElementID() on a non-object in /home/content/74/8620474/html/current_data.php on line 9

If anyone could help me that would be amazing, i have been struggling with this for hours.

This is my code:

```
<?php

function startElemHandler($parser, $name, $attribs) 
{
    if (strcasecmp($name, "current_observation") ==0 ) {
        echo "<div id='waves'>\n";
    }
    if (strcasecmp($name, "wave_height_ft") ==0) {
            $waveHeight->getbyElementID("wave_height_ft");

            echo $waveHeight->asXML();
    }

}

function endElemHandler($parser, $name)
{ 
    if (strcasecmp($name, "current_observation") ==0 ) {
        echo "</div>";
    }

}

$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_set_element_handler($parser, startElemHandler, endElemHandler);
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);

$strXML = implode("",file("http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/41009.xml"));

xml_parse($parser, $strXML);

xml_parser_free($parser);


?>
```

Comment: Could you include more of your code? As far as I can see `$waveHeight` isn't anything, which is why you're getting the "non-object" error. Is `$waveHeight` defined earlier in your code, before the function call?

Comment: Also, I don't have experience with the XML parser you're using, but you might want to look into using SimpleXML, it is very easy to use: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: where is $waveHeight declared ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few fundamental flaws with your code but you are essentially asking how to parse an XML file. I suggest using PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) with [`DOMXPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to extract the data you need. Here is some example code:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('weather.xml');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($xml);
$domx = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $domx->evaluate("//wave_height_ft");
$arr = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $arr[] = '<' . $entry->tagName . '>' . $entry->nodeValue .  '</' . $entry->tagName . '>';
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct, after reading about DOMXPATh i was able to pull off exactly what i wanted using a variation of the code you provided. - the only information i need from the element is   $entry->nodeValue; so i singled that out, thank you!!

Comment: so say i wanted to pull another element from the same xml document, would i just add another line under $entries = $domx->evaluate("//wave_height_ft");
 with and evaluate another field and then define it in the variable below as well?

Answer (score 0):

$waveHeight seem not defined (not in scope) wher you try to use it!

you can

- pass it as argument
- use the **global** statement
- create a class